# Is it possible to have a Plant Companion without the Treesinger archetype?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

Within RAW, is there another way to qualify for the [Treesinger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/elf/treesinger-druid-elf/)'s Plant Companions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm aware of only one other option, [the Supernaturalist Druid](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/supernaturalist-druid-archetype), which has the following feature:

> **Eldritch Botanist (Ex)**
>
> A supernaturalist can affect plants with mind-affecting effects she creates and with spells that normally affect animals. Any such spell that allows a Will save can instead be negated by the target plant with a successful Fortitude save at the same DC. **She also can choose plant bond and green empathy, as a treesinger druid, in place of nature bond and wild empathy.**

Bolding mine. It explicitly calls out the option of getting the plant bond feature from the Treesinger.

Comment: Ah, Google failed me. Nice find.

Answer (score 1):

Paizo has not published any option for non-treesingers to gain plant companions. The closest available is the [Grow Plant Creature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/grow-plant-creature-item-creation/) feat, but that is not the same thing at all.

Comment: I looked at that, but agree that it's not close enough for my intent. Good post for people who are looking to have Plant allies instead of Companions though

Answer (score -1):

The hunter archtype plant master from ultimate wilderness gains a plant companion, but it can't choose from the treesinger list (I THINK)

Comment: When posting an answer you should back up your answer with evidence and citations. It is generally not useful to post information that you are unsure of. The easy way to improve this would be to look it up and find out for  sure, then post that as an answer with the citation!  You can always [edit] your answer to improve it (and I would highly recommend doing so).

Comment: Is [this](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter/archetypes/paizo-hunter-archetypes/plant-master-hunter-archetype/) the archetype you're speaking of?